# Async function return undefined, but console.log works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get some information from a database in phpmyadmin using sequelize, but when I try to return the values I get "undefined". If I try to console.log the data, it appears just fine. I don't really understand what the problem is.

UPDATE: I've tried using await getTweetInfo(), but I get an error saying that "await is only valid in async function". I need the string that this query should return for another function.

```
async function getTweetInfo(){
    const data = await sequelize.query('SELECT contenido FROM tweets WHERE id = ?',
    {replacements: [2], type:sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    return data
}

getTweetInfo()
```

Comment: where is it getting `undefined`? you're not assigning the return value of `getTweetInfo()` to anything at all in that code - by the way `getTweetInfo()` will return a Promise

Comment: Where is the console in your code?

Answer (score 2):

```
async function getTweetInfo(){
    const data = await sequelize.query('SELECT contenido FROM tweets WHERE id = ?',
    {replacements: [2], type:sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    return data
}

console.log(await getTweetInfo());
```

[UPDATE]
I thought it was obvious but let me give a few considerations.

1. function **getTweetInfo** returns a Promise which will get resolved once data is returned from database
2. thus, when calling that function with an intent to consume the data, one should use **await**

example i gave is awaiting the result of the function and showing it in console.log()

Comment: @Trenton McKinney sure, thanks for reminder. answer is updated.

Answer (score 2):

getTweetInfo returns a Promise.

Try:

```
getTweetInfo().then(data => console.log(data))
```

Or use await

```
await getTweetInfo()
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as they point out the function returns a promise

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got the result is that you put the `console.log(data)` after `await`. It will wait the query until it finishes and then next to your `console.log(data)`. That's why you got the result.

```js
async function getTweetInfo(){
    return sequelize.query('SELECT contenido FROM tweets WHERE id = ?',
    {replacements: [2], type:sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
}

var data = await getTweetInfo()
console.log(data)
```